# PHP checking empty fields passed by another page

Tags: php, session-variables

I need to check if a username and a password passed by another page are empty but this doesn't work and I can't understand why. Username and password are passed by a form in another page with POST method.

```
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['username'])) && !(isset($_SESSION['password']))){
        $_SESSION['username']=trim($_POST['username']); 
        $_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];
}
```

[...]

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
if($username=="" || $password=="")
{
    echo "<script> 
        alert('You need to fill all fields!'); 
        window.location.assign('reg.php');
        </script>";
}
```

Thanks.

Edit.
Now with this:

```
if(is_null($username) || is_null($password))
{
    echo "<script> 
        alert('You need to fill all fields!'); 
        window.location.assign('reg.php');
        </script>";
}
else
{
    if(strlen($username)<5 || strlen($password)<5)
    {
        echo "<script> 
        alert('Fiels must be at least of 5 character!'); 
        window.location.assign('reg.php');
        </script>";
    }
```

It jumps directly to the second error message, 'Fiels must be at least of 5 character!'.
Why?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you see if you add  `print_r($_SESSION);` before `if($username ...` line?

Comment: Array ( [username] => [password] => )

Comment: Try: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))`

Comment: So the username and password key in your $_SESSION array are empty. Can you confirm you are setting it right? for example check if `$_POST['username']` has any data in it ?

Comment: Just like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your now checking if the username and password is empty. `$username = ""`

But when someone skipped an input it is null. So you have to check that. You can do that with the `is_null()` function.

So now you do: `is_null($username)`

Comment: In PHP they are the same thing.

Comment: is_null() seems to work; but I don't know why now I see the error message of the next statement, which controls if the fields are of a minimum length...but it must show the error message related to a blank field!

Answer (score 2):

You can check empty(). and you can use header location instead of javascript redirection.

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
if(empty($username) || empty($password))
{
header("Location: reg.php");
}
```

Comment: I've just tried with empty(), nothing changes. I've just edited my initial message.

Comment: Sorry Rashid but your solution simply redirects on the previous page; before that I need to display at least an error message!

Comment: So, you can set an error message if username or password are empty before redirecting to page, and print over there by checking variable message.

Comment: I don't know why but empty() seems that doesn't work. is_null() is fine. Thank you for your kind reply.